# Build nuget package with Bazel

Tags: .net, .net-core, bazel

I'm trying to convert a gRPC protos to client nuget packages using Bazel.
At the moment I'm able to build client DLLs but surprisingly I didn't find a simple way to pack them into a nugget package. What will be the best way to approach this problem?